# Difference between get_userdata() and get_currentuserinfo()

Tags: functions

I've already read the WordPress documentation for those functions, but is still unclear for me where is the difference between:

`get_userdata()` vs `get_currentuserinfo()`

As far as I know the `get_userdata()` require a parameter such as `user_id` or something else that's all, and `get_currentuserinfo()` does not.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Please revisit all your old posts and accept all answers that solved your issue. You can accept the best answer by clicking on the check mark on the left of the answer just below the up and downvote arrow. That checkmark will go green which will show that that answer is the one which solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

`get_userdata()` returns you the data of a specific user (by id), while `get_currentuserinfo()` returns data about the current logged in user.

For example, you could use `get_currentuserinfo()` to welcome a user (e.g. "Welcome back John"), if he's signed in.

Comment: and what's the difference between get_currentuserinfo() vs wp_get_current_user()? I am developing a restricted website with all personal information. That is why i am looking/searching for any information about userinfo/userdata how to create, read, update or delete. Any tips, articles?

Comment: They are very similar. You can find more about them on the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user